# VBulletin 3.6, disable "Invalid SQL" errors

Tags: security, vbulletin

VBulletin likes to dump SQL query and database metadata in case of query-error. I do not find it entertaining from security point of view.

Is there a way to disable this and just show "something went wrong, please try again later" to the users?

I tried to look for this on search-engines, old support-forums, but it just looks like I'm the first person who cares about it. Either that, or my search-foo is really weak today :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be more concerned that you're using a product six years out of date and out of patch support. Only 3.8.7 PL5 and above are being actively maintained for patching exploits.

That said, there's a template for the database error page. I believe it's in `includes/database_error_message.html`, but that version may have a different location. You can edit it as you see fit to show the information you want when an error occurs.

Comment: that's definitely among my concerns. thanks @Hyppy! sql-related message is generated in `includes/class_core.php`, but template seems like a good place for suppressing it.